# Boolean Indexing along the row axis of a DataFrame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
a = [ [1,2,3,4,5], [6,np.nan,8,np.nan,10]]
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], index=['foo', 'bar'])

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
     a    b  c    d   e
foo  1  2.0  3  4.0   5
bar  6  NaN  8  NaN  10
```

I understand how normal boolean indexing works, for example if I want to select the rows that have `c > 3` I would write `df[df.c > 3]`. However, what if I want to do that along the row axis. Say I want only the columns that have `'bar' == np.nan`.

I would have assumed that the following should do it due to the similarly of `df['a']` and `df.loc['bar']`:

```
df.loc[df.loc['bar'].isnull()]
```

But it doesn't, and obviously neither does `results[results.loc['hl'].isnull()]` giving the same error `*** pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided`

So how would I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you want to use the boolean mask to mask the columns:

```
In [135]:
df[df.columns[df.loc['bar'].isnull()]]

Out[135]:
       b    d
foo  2.0  4.0
bar  NaN  NaN
```

Or you can use `ix` and decay the series to np array:

```
In [138]:
df.ix[:,df.loc['bar'].isnull().values]

Out[138]:
       b    d
foo  2.0  4.0
bar  NaN  NaN
```

The problem here is that the boolean series returned is a mask on the columns:

```
In [136]:
df.loc['bar'].isnull()

Out[136]:
a    False
b     True
c    False
d     True
e    False
Name: bar, dtype: bool
```

but your index contains none of these column values as the labels hence the error so you need to use the mask against the columns or you can pass a np array to mask the columns in `ix`